# Why is Human Verification required to do a search?

Tags: support, captcha

I regularly use various StackExchange sites via browser Quick Search presets created via the context menu on the search box (on Chrome the menu item is 'Add as search engine...'.)

I've noticed over the past couple of months that I frequently get directed to the Human Verification step. I applaud how minimally invasive this is -- on Chrome, I just have to check the 'I am a human' box and it's done -- but nevertheless I am confused: Why must I confirm that I'm a human to do a search? Couldn't that wait until I perform some action that could cause harm to the site in some way if done poorly (voting, commenting, posting, etc.)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting my answer from [Why am I being redirected to a captcha when I am just searching?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253524/why-am-i-being-redirected-to-a-captcha-when-i-am-just-searching/253526#253526) over on Meta.SE:

> Searching takes resources too, and apparently some robots have been trying to use the search engine a lot lately. The captcha is there to limit that abuse.

Comment: TL;dr: we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Braiam Jeez, the things that pass for "TL" these days... :'(

Comment: +1 for disclosing the existence of meta.stackexchange.com. While looking for a place to post my question, I actually thought to myself 'it's too bad that all the meta sites are specific to the corresponding main site; this question is not specific to any of them'. But I didn't go so far as to type in meta.stackexchange.com on a lark. =)